# Drawing on Canvas without extending it?

Tags: java, canvas, frame

In order to draw images and or shapes in my JFrame, I use a very common method that works.

I use a class that extends canvss, make my own custom JFrame object then add my own class (which extends camvas). Then, I override the 'paint' method in order to paint on the canvas.

Basicly, here is an example: http://pastebin.com/KhZudT3r

This whole process works perfectly,  but I was wondering if there's a way to draw on a jframe (perferebly a canvas) without having to extend the canvas class?

Thanks,

Jake

Comment: **Never** draw directly on `JFrame` itself. instead draw on `JPanel` and then add it in `JFrame`

Comment: Could you give me an example?  And would I have to extend a class (and override and method) ?

Comment: No, not really - or more to the point, not one which will work well with the passive rendering model of Swing

Answer (score 1):

Try with `JPanel` and override `paintComponent()` method for your custom painting.

- **Don't** forget to call `super.paintComponent(g)` in overridden method.
- **Never** draw directly on `JFrame` itself instead draw on `JPanel` and then add it into `JFrame`

Sample code:

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel() {
    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
      super.paintComponent(g);

      //your custom drawing here
    }
};
```